# SonarQube support for jdk 1.5

Tags: sonarqube

Does anyone know what version(s) of SonarQube supports jdk 1.5? I have a legacy code base in Java that is compiled with jdk 1.5 that I would like to analyze using SonarQube. Thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can then go with the latest and greatest 4.5.1.

Note that the server and analyzer won't run on JDK 1.5, but you can use a recent JDK to analyze your legacy code.